# Why my process has been killed?

Tags: linux-kernel, out-of-memory, linux-mint

I have a program, written on C/C++ by myself, that is killed by Linux. The message "killed" appears. Willing to dig out the problem I observed inside the file /var/log/kern.log:

```
  Out of memory: Kill process 3915 (my_proj) score 236 or sacrifice child
  Killed process 3915 (my_proj) total-vm:5503376kB, anon-rss:3857420kB, file-rss:40kB
```

I do not know how to read this information and if there is some useful information to understand why this killed happened.  Can you help me?

Comment: Checkout: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128642/debug-out-of-memory-with-var-log-messages

Comment: Also:  http://java.dzone.com/articles/out-memory-kill-process-or

Comment: @SambhavSharma Thank you for your second link. It's helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are victim of the Linux OOM Killer.

You can tune the way that the OOM killer handles OOM conditions with certain processes. for example, your my_proj process 3915 that was killed earlier. 
If you want it not to be killed by the OOM killer, you can :

echo -15 > /proc/3915/oom_adj

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let's suppose that I run again my script. A new pin should be assigned "xxxx". Should I just write:    echo -15 > /proc/xxxx/oom_adj? Does this have collateral effects?

Comment: I have a second question. I get this error also while running my program on a computer with large memory capacity and OS ubuntu. Would you suggest me to use the same command there?

Comment: 1 - yes : the collateral effect is that your process won't be killed, but some others will be. 2 - yes ubuntu is a linux based distro. 3 - you maybe have memory leaks !